# rubix stacked-multi-series-bar-chart

Tags: javascript, charts, reactjs

This is the chunk of code am using to display the above chart.When am using the rubix stacked-multi-series-bar-chart , the x-axis is getting duplicated.How to avoid this?[This is the duplication on x-axis of chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H5kI.png)

```
chart = new Rubix('#stacked-multi-series-bar-chart', {
      title: self.state.question,
      //subtitle: 'Comparison across employee groups',
      titleColor: '#EE682F',
      subtitleColor: '#EE682F',
      height: 300,
      axis: {            
        x: {
          type: 'ordinal',
        },
        y:  {
          type: 'linear',
          tickFormat: self.state.absoluteActive?'.0f':'%'
        }
      },
      grouped: true,
      show_markers: true
    });
     var series = chart.bar_series({
          name: department,
          color: colors[index]
        });
series.addData(seriesData);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H5kI.png)

Comment: 1 - please put question in question, not in title (should be a summary)  2 - dont put a link on image (will die), instead insert image . Edit question to correct these two points (click on "edit" at the bottom of question)

Comment: Thanks for that kebs